# calling one perl file from the second perl file while taking variables of second file

Tags: perl

I want to know if this is possible. the file a.pm has few variables that will be required by b.pl. and b.pl is called by a.pm

```
 a.pm
    {
    $var1,$var2;
    system (perl b.pl);
    }

b.pl 
{
print "$var1";
}
```

How do I make use of $var1 and $var2 to b.pl. I Do not want to pass as Command line arguments to b.pl

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make the code valid so it at least compiles. The code of your a.pm has a syntax error. Also, is it relevant that _a_ is a module and _b_ is a script? Are you using `strict` and `warnings`? You should always do that in new code (although it's not relevant to this problem).

Comment: What about OOP approach? Create 2 modules `a.pm` and `b.pm`. Have an object in each module, and after creating the object for module1, create the object for module2 and send him the arguments from module1

Comment: (1) Please provide a reasonable script.  This isn't even a sketch.  (2) As for your edit -- what do you mean by "_Do not want to pass as Command line arguments_"?  How are `a.pm`, the code that uses it, and `b.pl` related?

Comment: I'd bet this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot share the same variables if you do a system call to a new Perl interpreter. To do that, you could pass them as command line arguments.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $var1 = 'foo';
my $var2 = 'bar';

system( 'perl b.pl', $var1, $var2);
```

And then in b.pl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print $ARGV[0];
```

The arguments end up in [`@ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40ARGV), which can be used as a regular array. If you want to share data structures, you'd have to serialize them first. You could use [Storable](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/Storable) or [JSON](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/JSON) to do that. You then need to deserialize them in your second program.

There are more complicated alternatives, but I think going into detail for those (like saving to a file, opening a pipe and reading from STDOUT in the second script) are a bit out of scope.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass **`$var1`** and **`var2`** from ***a.pm*** to ***b.pl*** along with the command execution using system. Please the check the following:

**a.pm**

```
my ($var1,$var2);
$var1="Open";
$var2="Close";
system ("perl b.pl $var1 $var2");
```

**b.pl**

```
my $var1=$ARGV[0];
my $var2=$ARGV[1];
print "$var1";
```

The output will be:

***Open***

**If you don't need to send value by command line please try the following.** 
The way to do is by passing value by setting it in **%ENV** hash as given in the following program. Please be careful when you set the key for it so that it won't replace the existing %ENV keys.

**a.pm**

```
my ($var1,$var2);
$var1="Open";
$var2="Close";
$ENV{m_temp_x_var1}=$var1;
$ENV{m_temp_x_var2}=$var2;
system ("perl b.pl");
```

**b.pl**

```
my $var1=$ENV{m_temp_x_var1};
my $var2=$ENV{m_temp_x_var2};
print "$var1";
```

The output will be:

***Open***

Comment: The output will be _$var1_. You need to use double quotes `""` to get interpolation on your `system` call, or pass the variables as additional args to `system` to also get proper shell escaping for free.

Comment: @simbabque Sorry I forgot.